# GA4 - Empty transaction metrics for custom event in Explore

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

In GA4, I am using a custom event to send AB Tests metadata from my Adobe Target experiences.

The code is as follows:

```
​ window.gtag('event', 'ab_test', {
  'test_name':'${campaign.name}',
  'test_id':'${campaign.id}',
  'variation_name':'${campaign.recipe.name}',
  'variation_id':'${campaign.recipe.id}',
})
```

Checking the network requests and the Debug View I know that the data is properly sent (and received).

In the Explore reporting feature I have created a Free from report with my AB Test Variation Name as a dimension, AB Test Name as a column, and Conversions, Transactions, Purchase Revenue as metrics.

[image]

Furthermore, I have created 2 segments, one identifying visitors having an ab_test event count > 0 and the other < 0. This segment is created at a User scope. (also tried at a session scope). But in any case, all the metrics always end up empty.

[image]

[image]

My expectation is obviously that I could correlate the exposure to an AB Test to sales and other conversion metrics.

Any idea why the data isn't showing up?